# Error at selector on shared component at the Angular modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a common component in my directory ( it is a loader )

```
loader
 loader.component.html
 loader.component.ts
```

Login uses loader to show it when the page is loading, this is the tree

```
login
 login.component.html
 login.module.ts
 login.component.ts
```

I have this code for **login.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent, LoaderComponent],
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  exports: [ LoaderComponent ]
```

I used exports array to use everywhere

I want to use it here

```
landpage
 newUser
   newUser.component.html
   newUser.component.ts
   newUser.module.ts
 landpage.component.html
 landpage.module.ts
 landpage.component.ts
```

This is the **landpage.module.ts** code

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LandingPageComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LoginModule,
    NewUserModule
  ]
})
```

I imported LoginModule, thinking it has inside declared the LoaderComponent

And finally this is the **newUser.component.html**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [NewUserComponent],
  imports: [ CommonModule ]
})
```

when I try to use the selector on newUser.component.html

```
<app-loader [loading]='loading.asObservable()'></app-loader>
```

And I got this error

> Can't bind to 'loading' since it isn't a known property of
>   'app-loader'.

***The loader works fine, because I used on login at first time, the errors came when I tried to use it on another modules.***

Where I must to declare the loaderComponent to be shared by all the pages in my app?

login, loader and landpage are at the same level of the app's tree

I'm learning the structure of Angular, If this is not the best way to do, I accept suggestions

**ADDING loader code**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.sass']
})

export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() loading: Observable<boolean>;
  public subscription: Subscription;
  public display = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.loading.subscribe( ( data: boolean ) => this.display = data );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

I use it as this way

```
public loading: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

this.loading.next( true );
```

Comment: Please add the actual component classes. My gut feeling is you probably did not decorate using `Input()` or maybe something is marked private but those are guesses because you did not include the code.

Comment: I included @Igor

Comment: Mark it as `public` also as that is what you are doing with other public fields: `@Input() public loading: Observable<boolean>;` Also make sure the component that loads `app-loader` also has a `loading` property.

Comment: Done, but still not working :(

Comment: this `this.loading.subscribe( ( data: boolean ) => this.display = data )` is completely useless. It can be replaced with `@Input() display: boolean` instead and `[display]="loading | async"`. You're creating a lot of extra work for yourself.

Comment: The newUserModule doesn't import the LoginModule, where the loader component is declared and exported. So it doesn't have access to the loader component.

Comment: Must I import on all Modules? I not enough to import on LandPageModule?

Answer (score 0):

You should either import the login module to the newUserModule or import the newUserComponent to the LandingPageModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LandingPageComponent, NewUserComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LoginModule
  ]
})
```

or:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [NewUserComponent],
  imports: [ CommonModule, LoginModule ]
})
```